# Adding in the iAd App Network

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iad

I just finished adding in the iAd App network code into my game and I was wondering if there were any other steps. It appears that you only have to fill out the contract and banking info, but I know with adMob you have to add in the Publisher ID that they supply and link the app.

Just wondering if you have to do the same with iAd? (programatically that is, is there anything to add in other than the code to make the advertisements appear?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, enable iAd in iTunes Connect for each of your Apps:

[image]